# Pop up is not working correct, does not refresh the page

Tags: php, javascript, html, popup, page-refresh

I try to open pop up in the same window, but it forwards me to another. Also, I try to refresh window after pop up closes, but I don't find easy solution. I think the best is not to put # to the URL. That is my function:

```
<li value="Open window" >
    <a href="javascript: window.open('upd.php?m=<?php echo $oldpar?>','','width=520,height=400')">
        <u>EDIT</u>
    </a>
</li>
```

I manage open the window, however main page also goes to `javascript: window.open('upd.php?m=2','','width=520,height=400')`. I tried to put:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function refreshParent()
    {
        window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;

        if (window.opener.progressWindow)
        {
            window.opener.progressWindow.close()
        }

        window.close();
    }
    //-->
</script>
```

It would be great to close pop up automatically after user select variables and press button. Immediately after the parent(main) URL would refresh.. Any help? :)

P.s. any ideas how to auto refresh pop up? I saw all browsers have different way of doing that.. Common one?

Comment: Add `return false;` after `close()`

Comment: at first problem with the <li value="Open window" ><a href="javascript: window.open('upd.php?m=<?php echo $oldpar?>','','width=520,height=400')"><u>EDIT</u></a></li>
I cannot find how to leave main page not to be forwarded while pop up window will jump. When I press button EDIT pop up opens and parent window goes to javascript: window.open('upd.php?m=2','','width=520,height=400'). Parent window should stay in the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use "_self" as the window title (second parameter to `window.open()`) to open the pop up in the same window.
- Use `window.location.reload();` to reload the current window.
- Use `opener.location.reload();` to reload the window that opened the popup before calling `window.close();`

Comment: Thank you :) It is the best answer.. I used:
?><script type="text/javascript">opener.location.reload(); setTimeout("self.close()",3000);</script><?php

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I guess you've been looking for that.

```
​<ul>
<li value="Open window" ><a href="javascript: window.open('upd.php?m=<?php echo $oldpar>','','width=520,height=400'); return false;"><u>EDIT</u></a></li>
</ul>
```

`return false;` at the end of the call should solve your problem.

**UPD:**

http://jsfiddle.net/Mt8Vd/

Answer (score 0):

To open the windows via link:

```
<a href="javascript:open('400','360','account.php?id=<?=$id?>&type=<?=$type?>');">Open</a>
```

The js function to open a link:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function open(w,h,URL)
{
  var width = w;
  var height = h;
  var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
  var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);    
  window.open(URL,'janela', 'width='+width+', height='+height+', top='+top+', left='+left+', scrollbars=yes, status=no, toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, menubar=no, resizable=no, fullscreen=no');
}
</script>
```

And Finally in the end of your "popup" you should close the windows after all task get done, just telling the script to close the popup and reload the opener page.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function close()
{
    opener.location.reload();
    window.close();
}
</script>
```

Comment: `reload` takes a boolean, not a string. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

Comment: You right, sorry I had corrected a mistake, you need just a close() ... :D

Comment: <a href="javascript:open('400','360','account.php?id=<?=$id?>&type=<?=$type?>');">Open</a> not working, my browser even stops working for several secs, mhhm.. I think I could use <a href=javascript:void window.open("http:// 

It is perfectly OK. Just window does not resize automatically, but it is not so big problem. I need to refresh it after pop up closes..

Comment: call the function open(w,h,URL) first in your script, after create your link to your popup. Here works well, I'm using Firefox 11.0 with OpenSuse 11.4.